# Break jquery ajax deferred chain

Tags: jquery, ajax

I would like to break out of a jquery ajax deferred chain so it does not keep executing subsequent actions.

I am making my site work using both ajax navigation and direct links. I am using nodejs/express and I want to either send native redirect requests if it is not ajax or use window.location to redirect from jquery if the request is ajax.

I have the logic in express working just fine to send redirect or an error.
What I would like is to check the request status in jquery and if it sees a redirect code execute a window.location.

Right now the only redirect I have is if the user is trying to access a page that requires authentication, but I will have others to fill out later once I get this working.

What currently happens is the target div gets populated with the error message while the redirect is starting. Instead I would like to just break the deferred chain and let the window.location do its work.

```
$.ajax({
    url: options.url,
    method: options.method,
    data: options.data
})
.always(function( data_jqXHR, textStatus, jqXHR_errorThrown ) {
    if (textStatus === 'success') {
        var jqXHR = jqXHR_errorThrown;
    } else {
        var jqXHR = data_jqXHR;
    }
    var data = jqXHR.responseJSON;

    switch (jqXHR.status) {
        case 401:
            window.location = "/login?error=session_expired";
            // I would like to stop execution here because I am redirecting
            break;
    }   
})
.done(function(data) {
    $("#" + options.target).html(data);
})
.fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, error) {
    $("#" + options.target).html("Error loading page: " + error);
})
.always(function() {
    if (options.popup) {
        if (!($("#" + options.target + "_container").data('bs.modal') || {}).isShown) {
            $("#" + options.target + "_container").modal('show');
        }
    }
    if (options.hasOwnProperty('callback')) {
        options.callback();
    }
})
;
```